# Analytics is showing in Admob not in Adsense

Tags: admob, analytics, ads, adsense

**I have an Admob account linked to Adsense account** but whenever i check the reports in Admob account everything shows fine, but at when i check reports in Adsense it shows me 0 in everything. Below are the attached Screenshots of both account. And yes before this Admob account i was using another account with another one's Adsense linked, but from when i've migrated to a new Admob & Adsense account **analytics are showing in Admob only not in Adsense**.

**Admob Reports**

[image: Admob Reports]

**Adsense Reports**

[image: Adsense Reports]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i just **got a Notification from Adsense**. It says something about Admob metrics:

[image: Adsense Notification]